# Unix Shell CRLF to be replaced with space

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am using the following input for Oracle SQL Loader.
The file I downloaded as CSV from Service now is having a CRLF

I tried the

```
dos2unix 
tr '\n' ',' < input.txt > output.txt
awk '{printf "%s\r\n", $0}' file
```

but no luck.

Sample data :

```
"ID","NAME","GROUP","Free Text [CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
"
"ID1","NAME1","GROUP1","Free Text1 [CR][LF]
"
```

Desired Output :

```
"ID","NAME","GROUP","Free Text"
"ID1","NAME1","GROUP1","Free Text1"
```

Please suggest a code or command that will be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try again? It's not really clear. You can try with `sed` for example.

Comment: please edit your question and add the output of `sed -n l input.txt`.

Comment: Just typing `dos2unix` won't change anything - for starters you didn't specify a filename

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
$ perl -pe 'while(m/\r$/) { $_ .= readline }; s/\r\n//g' rgram.txt
"ID","NAME","GROUP","Free Text"
"ID1","NAME1","GROUP1","Free Text1"
```

This joins successive lines ending in CRLF (`\r$` or `\r\n`) into one long line, then strips all CRLF pairs from that line and prints it.

The modified input is printed to stdout, which can be redirected to another file.  Or use `perl`'s `-i` option to modify the original file in-place:

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe 'while(m/\r$/) { $_ .= readline }; s/\r\n//g' rgram.txt
```

This will keep the original as `rgram.txt.bak`.

I'm not a fan of using `-i`, I'd rather just redirect stdout to, e.g., `rgram.new`.  Writing to stdout is more versatile (you can pipe it into other programs, or use it in process or command substitution, etc) and there's less risk of a mistake trashing the original file.

---

`rgram.txt` is a text file containing the sample data as described in the question:

```
$ sed -n l rgram.txt 
"ID","NAME","GROUP","Free Text\r$
\r$
\r$
\r$
"$
"ID1","NAME1","GROUP1","Free Text1\r$
"$
```

Comment: Hello Cas, Thank you for the code snip, but it did not work.

Comment: if it did not work, then your text file is not as you described it in your question.   post a copy of an actual sample somewhere it can be downloaded, like on github / gist or one of the pastebin type services.

Comment: Thanks you Cas, I had found a work around with help of an SME, below is the command is used 
sed 's/"$//' rgram.csv | sed 's/$/"/' | sed '/^"$/d' > rgram.new.csv
I removed the last " character from the file first and then add it back and then remove the line starting with ".

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/"$//' rgram.csv | sed 's/$/"/' | sed '/^"$/d' > rgram.new.csv
```

I removed the last " character from the file first and then add it back and then remove the line starting with ".

Comment: That's extremely clumsy. `sed` is a scripting language; you can combine several commands in a single script.  `sed -e 's/"$//' -e 's/$/"/' -e 's/^"$/d' rgram.csv >rgram.new.csv`

Comment: or just `sed -e 's/"$//; s/$/"/; /^"$/d' rgram.csv >rgram.new.csv` (and even the spaces are the semi-colons are optional...they do help make it easier to read, though)

Comment: it's hard to see the point, though.  Why remove the `"` at the EOL and then put it back immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to remove the CRLF sequences but leave the LF without preceding CR alone, so:

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n//' < input.txt > output.txt
```

or:

```
gawk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS= 1 < input.txt > output.txt
```